# how to add logs easy to turn on when needed and turn off with no overhead for production?

Tags: c++

In my C# projects I like using `ConditionalAttribute` and find it very useful. I have a lot of classes for logging and just recompiling with corresponding condition attribute set or unset I can turn on or off logging (with no overhead).

```
// this code likely is not good as HedgerControllerLogger better to be singleton
// please ignore that

public class HedgerControllerLogger
{
    private StreamWriter swLog;

    public HedgerControllerLogger()
    {
        swLog = new StreamWriter("logsGeneral/logHedgerController.txt") { AutoFlush = true };
    }

    [Conditional("LOG_HEDGER_CONTROLLER")]
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        swLog.WriteLine(DateTimePrecise.Instance.CurDateTime().ToString("H:mm:ss:ffffff") + ' ' + message);
    }

}
```

How can I have same effect on c++? Should I use something similar? Probably some of existent logging libriries has the same functionality, probably `boost`? Thanks!

Comment: Preprocessor directives (`#ifdef`, `#ifndef`)?

Comment: recompiling does not mean you can easly activate the logs, easly activating the logs, means activating the logs while the system is up and running and you have no access to any development tools, such as a compiler...

Comment: @user1708860 i don't need easy activation. I need no overhead when logging are off. As i 1. use logs intensive 2. write low latency code. 3. need logs only for debugging and troubleshooting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084052/c-logging-library-recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at how `TRACE/ATLTRACE` and similar macros are provided (If I am correct, you are using Visual Studio). In general they boil down to having a tracing call in DEBUG builds, and a no-op in RELEASE build. Here is an example:

```
struct CTrace
{
    static void CTrace::Trace(LPCTSTR lpszFormat, ...)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, lpszFormat);
        TCHAR szBuffer[1024];
        int nSize = sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(szBuffer[0]);
        int nBuf = _vsntprintf(szBuffer, nSize, lpszFormat, args);          
        OutputDebugString(szBuffer); // write to debug output
        va_end(args);
    }    
};

#ifdef _DEBUG   
#define TRACE               CTrace::Trace
#else  
#define TRACE               true ? (void)0 : CTrace::Trace
#endif // _DEBUG
```

Then in the code you have something like:

```
TRACE("value is %d", 34);
```

In DEBUG build, this gets compiled to:

```
CTrace::Trace("value is %d", 34);
```

In release build, it turns to:

```
true ? (void)0 : CTrace::Trace("value is %d", 34);
```

which is then optimized away by the compiler. You can verify it by inspecting the generated code.

Comment: am I really should use this c-style macros? probaly boost logging library or another logging library can do that for me?

Comment: I'd say you should. I might be wrong, but AFAIK other logging libraries which provide the feature to remove logging in release build (so it is more like debug tracing, then real logging which should be enabled also in release builds) also rely on macros. e.g. boost-log (which is not a part of boost) has BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL macro

Comment: my initial question supports several files. I can create as much `StreamWriter` as I want and write to as many files as I want. Your version just prints to one destionation.

Comment: No, your initial question doesn't support multiple files, your code sample does. Your questions just asks for turning logging on/off, not for supporting multiple files, so I have answered what you have asked. Actually, you write to streams, not files, so I am not sure whether my example should also take that into account. Unfortunately, I can't guess all the requirements you have to provide exact implementation satisfying all your needs, so I leave it as an exercise for the reader. Feel free to extend the `CTrace::Trace` implementation to suit your needs. I would use NLog/Log4Net anyway

Answer (score 1):

You could use the preprocessor:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_LOGGING
  void log(const std::string& message) { /* do logging*/}
#else
  void log(const std::string&){}
#endif
```

You could also do something similar with templates, but why overcomplicate things?

Comment: are you sure that compiler will optimize and will not add extra method call which do nothing? I want NO overhead when logging is disabled.

Comment: @javapowered: that depends on exactly how you implement it. What I've shown above ensures that the `log` function's entire implementation is visible at the call site (if you do this in a header), and then it is trivial for the compiler to inline and optimize away. if you tuck this away in a .cpp file, it may or may not be optimized away, depending on compiler flags.

Comment: You could also just invoke a macro when you want to log: `#define LOG(x) /* do actual logging */`, and then just redefine that to do nothing when you want to disable logging. Then you're guaranteed it will have no effect.